# Perforce files stored in depot are twice as large

Tags: linux, disk-space, perforce

With this command

```
p4 sizes -a -s -h //depot/...
```

Perforce reports 11GB is used.

How ever if i manually check the server there is archive folder of size 21GB in perforce root folder.

Why is this? We have many binary files. But only 1 revision exist for those binary files. Because they are not edited and only submitted once.

How can I reclaim the space?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was we had a lot of orphaned archives caused by failed, or incomplete submits.

You can set the expiry time of archive by the `lbr.storage.delay` configurable. default is 86400. i.e 1 day after incomplete submit the archive is considered orphan.

The command that would save me 10GB was

```
p4 storage -y -d //...
```

this will delete unreferenced archives in all depots.

remove the `-y` option to preview what's going to happen.

you can use `-D numberOfSeconds` to override expiry time just for this command.